# PHP append a variable's value to variable name

Tags: php

I am a PHP beginner.
I want to create multiple variables and the name of those variables should have a value appended to it which depends on a counter variable of a for loop.

```
  foreach ( $xmlTagNames as $xmlKey => $xmlTagName )
  {
    if ($xmlTagName == "property")
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i ++)
        {
            $$xmlTagName = $xmlFile->createElement ( $xmlTagName );
        }
    }
   }
```

At the seventh line I want the variable names like 
$property0,$property1 etc. How could this be done?

Comment: This is what arrays are for.

Comment: Pretty much whenever you think you need *variable variables* (look for that term in the manual), you actually want *arrays* (look that up too). Yes, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @David said, arrays are probably what you should use:

```
$properties = array();
foreach ( $xmlTagNames as $xmlKey => $xmlTagName )
{
  if ($xmlTagName == "property")
  {
      for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i ++)
      {
          $properies[] = $xmlFile->createElement ( $xmlTagName );
      }
  }
}
```

Then you can access the properties using `$properies[0]`, `$properies[1]`, `$properies[2]` and `$properies[3]`.

But if you insist on creating variables with incrementing names you could use the following:

```
foreach ( $xmlTagNames as $xmlKey => $xmlTagName )
{
  if ($xmlTagName == "property")
  {
      for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i ++)
      {
          $variableName = $xmlTagName.$i;
          $$variableName = $xmlFile->createElement ( $xmlTagName );
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments: You should use an array here.

To answer your question though, use the following syntax:

```
${$xmlTagName . $i} = $xmlFile->createElement ( $xmlTagName );
```

Comment: Can you change the name of a variable during run time? Or am I understanding the question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments that you would be better using an array here

```
$properties = array();

foreach ( $xmlTagNames as $xmlKey => $xmlTagName )
{
    if ($xmlTagName == "property")
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i ++)
        {
            $properties['property' . $i] = $xmlFile->createElement ( $xmlTagName );
        }
    }
}

var_dump($properties);
```

If you are set on using variable variables

```
foreach ( $xmlTagNames as $xmlKey => $xmlTagName )
{
    if ($xmlTagName == "property")
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i ++)
        {
            $variableName = $xmlTagName . $i;
            $$variableName = $xmlFile->createElement ( $xmlTagName );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for double array, as the value of `$xmlTagName` is always `"property"` in `$properties[$xmlTagName][$i]`.